# Get all chunk items before processing?

Tags: java, spring-batch, jsr352

I use [Spring Batch](http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/) in a project and I'm looking for a way to pre-process all items of a `Chunk` before the `ItemProcessor` starts processing. I need to process the items of the chunk together.

There is a [`ChunkListener`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkListener), which is called only before the `ItemReader` starts, but not before the `ItemProcessor` starts. There is also a [`ChunkProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/ChunkProvider.html), which fills the chunk with items. But I found no documentation how to grab the filled chunk.

How can I access all items of `Chunk` after the [step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) finished reading?

Comment: I think this defeats the whole point of chunk processing. You might need another step before doing this, rather than doing it like that. Could you elaborate a little on why need the whole chunk ? Like, you need to calculate the average of the chunk or something like that ?

Comment: @Asoub The batches read and write to an database. Let’s assume the ItemReader reads 100k records/items of a table and the ItemProcessor needs per item another 100 joined records of other tables. For performance reason I want eager-load the joined records. If I eager-load the related records in the ItemReader, the batch needs to manage 10M records at once, which doesn’t work properly. Therefore I want to eager-load only the 500er item chunks before processing, which results in 0.15M records at once.

Comment: @sschmek I see. I had a problem like this, but not with a hundred JOINs per record !.. I used a successive temporary tables, with all join already done (maybe ten) and a manual RowMapper (bug-prone, but it was pretty efficient), but I'm not sure this is viable with hundreds of JOIN. What Reader and RowMapper (or ORM) are you currently using ?

Comment: Did you find the solution?